# Error: In download.file(url = blast_ftp, destfile = dwl_file, mode = "wb")

Tags: r

i am trying to run this command to install an R package dependencies but i get these errors, how can i fix it ? thank you

```
 buildDependencies(path_to_reference_data = "C:\\Users\\cc\\Desktop\\Data\\Tax4Fun\\Tax4Fun2_ReferenceData_v2", install_suggested_packages = T, use_force=T)
```

> Install Tax4Fun2 dependencies trying URL
> 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/executables/blast+/2.9.0/ncbi-blast-2.9.0+-x64-win64.tar.gz'
> downloaded 91.8 MB
>
> Error in system(command = blast_bin, intern = T) :
> 'C:\Users\cc\Desktop\Data' not found In addition: Warning message: In
> download.file(url = blast_ftp, destfile = dwl_file, mode = "wb") :
> the 'wininet' method is deprecated for ftp:// URLs

Comment: this is the same question you asked yesterday. Did you try `method = "curl"` as I suggested? Could you please tell us where you got the package from, since it is no longer available anywhere for anyone to help you with it? Perhaps you could give us an idea of what you are trying to do with this package, since there may be alternative ways to tackle your problem that don't require a defunct, unsupported package.

Comment: yes, it is the same question, i tried to contact the authors but they didn't receive my email. I am using Tax4Fun2 package to predict metabolic functions from 16SrRNA genes dataset. i tried what you suggest , still i have the same problem.

Comment: Yes Zee, but where did you get that package?

Comment: i worked with this package before. know it is not on github by the author page . i get frol here     https://github.com/fjossandon/Tax4Fun2

Comment: Hi Zee - the package is no longer maintained, and in its current format is not compatible with the latest version of R. It probably wouldn't be very difficult to fix it to work with the latest version of R, but it would require forking it on Github, fixing the buildDependencies function to use curl instead of wininet, and iinstalling from your new repo. This isn't too difficult, but a bit beyond a Stack Overflow answer to sort out.

Comment: Yes i know is difficult, Thank you very much for your kind support. i came back to my old folders where i stocked the dependencies. i have some progress with new results. i have now an error at the lat step. Thank you